# How to skip a particular empty field from appearing in XML file based on XSD file

Tags: xsd, bean-io

I have an XSD definition as :

```
<beanio xmlns="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03">
    <stream name="udraccess" format="xml">
    <parser class="org.beanio.stream.xml.XmlRecordParserFactory" />
.
..lines
..of
..XML code
                    <segment name="aggregationDimensions" class="java.util.HashMap" collection="list" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <segment name="aggregationDimension" class="java.util.HashMap" collection="list" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <field name="aggregationDimensionType" xmlType="element" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <field name="aggregationThresholdDimensionUnitType" xmlType="element" minOccurs="0" />
                            <field name="aggregationDimensionValue" xmlType="element" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <segment name="aggregationDimensionAverageInfo" class="java.util.HashMap" collection="list" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <field name="averageValueTotal" xmlType="element" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <field name="averageValueCount" xmlType="element"  minOccurs="0"/>
                                <field name="averageValuePerType" xmlType="element" minOccurs="0"/>
                            </segment>
                        </segment>
                    </segment>
```

Now in this particular segment: `aggregationDimensionAverageInfo`, I need that if this value is not present in the input XML, the output XML file should not have that field at all... Currently I am getting the field as an empty array, I want that it should be skipped completely if missing:

```
                    "aggregationDimensions": [
                        {
                            "aggregationDimension": [
                                {
                                    "aggregationDimensionAverageInfo": [],
                                    "aggregationDimensionType": "106",
                                    "aggregationDimensionValue": "15:"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
```

If that field is present in the input XML, I get it alright as below:

```
                    "aggregationDimensions": [
                        {
                            "aggregationDimension": [
                                {
                                    "aggregationDimensionAverageInfo": [
                                        {
                                            "averageValuePerType": "50",
                                            "averageValueTotal": "50",
                                            "averageValueCount": "1"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "aggregationDimensionType": "106",
                                    "aggregationDimensionValue": "0:15"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
```

I need help with the scenario where its missing from the input XML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `lazy` attribute on the `segment` to `true`.

```
<segment name="aggregationDimensionAverageInfo" lazy="true" class="java.util.HashMap" collection="list" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
    <field name="averageValueTotal" xmlType="element" minOccurs="0"/>
    <field name="averageValueCount" xmlType="element"  minOccurs="0"/>
    <field name="averageValuePerType" xmlType="element" minOccurs="0"/>
</segment>
```

The [reference guide](https://beanio.github.io/docs/reference-guide#a11-segment) state the following for the lazy attribute on a segment:

> If set to true, the class or collection bound to this segment will
> only be instantiated if at least one child attribute is not null or
> the empty String. Defaults to false. This functionality differs from
> minOccurs in that the fields may still exist in the input stream.